# Pygame black background has a distorted/broken image

Tags: python, pygame

I started a basic project with pygame and tried to set up the basics.

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (200, 200, 200)
SIZE = width, height = 500, 700

def main() -> None:
    global SCREEN
    pygame.init()

    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Tetronur')
    running = True
    SCREEN.fill(BLACK)

    while running:
        draw()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        
        

def draw():
    rect = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 400, 600)
    pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, WHITE, rect, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But the thing is, when I run the code, I get a screen looking like this:

[image: ??]

**PS:** I use Python 3.9.6 and Pygame 2.0.1

Comment: You need to call `pygame.display.update()` at some point to update the display, at the end of `draw` for example.  Otherwise, all drawings you make have no visible effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame draws to a hidden screen, you must call pygame.display.flip() or pygame.display.update() after drawing so that this hidden screen is displayed to the actual screen.